# Trying to have two different subdomains share a cookie, but can't set cookie with top level domain from subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

I have a php application in the domain "subdomain.example.com" and I need to set a cookie that is also readable by "subdomain2.example.com".

So I tried making a cookie using the `setcookie()` function using the domain ".example.com", but it refuses to make the cookie. There are no error messages or anything, but when I try to print out the `$_COOKIE` global, the cookie I'm trying to generate is not there nor can I find it when I search through the cookies in the browser.

I have already modified the php.ini file to contain the line
`session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`

If it helps, I am running this off an Apache 2 web server.

Comment: I used `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');` to get two sites with different subdomains to share cookies.

Comment: I forgot to say that I also changed the php.ini file to read `session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`